# How to intercept android bottom navigation bar visibility after swipe up

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

My Xamarin.Android MVVMCross fragment implements View.IOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
Here is fragment `OnViewCreated` method

```
View _decorview = ParentActivity.Window.DecorView;
_decorview.SetOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(this);
var uiOptions =
                SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
                SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
            _decorview.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
```

Here is an `OnSystemUiVisibilityChange` method:

```
public void OnSystemUiVisibilityChange([GeneratedEnum] StatusBarVisibility visibility)
        {
            if (((int)visibility & (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation) == 0)
            {
                if (ParentActivity.BottomNavigation != null)
                    ParentActivity.BottomNavigation.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ParentActivity.BottomNavigation != null)
                    ParentActivity.BottomNavigation.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
        }
```

But this method doesn't calls when I swipe up to show navigation bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flag `SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky` prevent receiving a callback when the system UI visibility changes

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accept your answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) after two days, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

AlexTsy.

I agree that the documentation states ImmersiveSticky prevents receiving the callback.

However, when I moved to Android 10 I had problems with all my StickyImmersive screens on rotation. There would be spurious system bar reappearances. Not every rotation, but rotate enough times and they would start appearing. All these screens worked fine with Android 9 and lower and still do without the callback, but any Android 10 device needs the callback. In desperation, I tried adding a View.IOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener to the fragment and that fixed it. The additional code didn't have any adverse effect on the devices with Android 9 or less.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll keep it on mind.
I replaced `ImmersiveSticky` to `Immersive`